# Как убрать абзац (отступ) в Word 2016?

Tags: ms-word

Как убрать отступы в Word 2016? Раньше работала в версии 2007 года, но вчера перешла в версию 2016 и не могу теперь убрать отступы

Answer (score 1):

Отступы можно задать во вкладке "Макет"
Абзацы обычно я убираю backspace, а делаю Tab

Answer (score 0):

Есть 3 варианта:

1)Щелчками мышкой расставить на верхней линейке позиции табуляции там, где Вы хотите сделать отступ. Где щелкните - в эту позицию текст и будет смещаться.

2)На вкладке Главная, в группе Абзац, нажмите кнопку вызова диалогового окна Абзац, а затем нажмите кнопку Табуляция. В поле Позиции табуляции введите расположение (длину) на линейке, где требуется добавить позицию табуляции. Или задайте шаг табуляции по умолчанию поменьше.

3)Выделите весь текст, нажав на клавиатуре комбинацию CTRL + A, нажмите правую кнопку мыши — Абзац — и в окне установите значение всех отступов — 0 или любое требуемое значение — ОК.